# Find out what causes beach ball when running Sheepshaver

Tags: macos, crash

This is a very weird case and I've searched around in a lot of user forums, but nowhere was an answer or not even a vague explanation. So I'm hoping, someone here has an idea where to search.

I downloaded and setup Sheepshaver on my MacBook pro running the latest Catalina. No matter what I do, Sheepshaver hangs with a beach ball. (ROM file provided and valid.) Doing exact the same setup under another user or on another Mac, Sheepshaver runs fine. I have no firewall, no antivirus running or anything else that could restrict file or network access. I've checked permissions, ACLs, moved it to another location, re-downloaded the application and ROM file. No success. The only thing that works is running it via terminal and `sudo`. But that's not the desired way.

So how would one analyze what's causing a beach ball with an application, when the application itself doesn't provide a log file?

Comment: You could use the XCode tools to have a closer look at where it spends its time.

Comment: If it runs with `sudo`, it's most probably a permissions issue. You could launch Sheepshaver with `sudo`, run `ps` to get its PID and run`lsof -p PID` to check the directories and files it's accessing. That may give you a hint.